# passing jar file in java code

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a function that requires the path of a jar file

```
builder.add(EventAnnotator.createAnnotatorDescription("/org/apache/ctakes/temporal/ae/eventannotator/model.jar"));
```

This refers to the jar file in my resource folder (as far as I can understand).
I have the same jar file in my maven local repo. and want to use it instead.
Is there a way to pass it as a string like this ?

Comment: Having a jar file in resources folder does not make sense. You should have that as dependency etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise ok. But after using it as a dependency, how do I refer it in the java code ?

Comment: Why do you need to refer a jar file in your java code? You usually use classes of a jar file which is defined as dependency or maybe a resource inside that jar file (should be done like that). ?

Comment: These .jar files are basically the zip files which contain the model of the annotator (as used in NLP) that are being used. I could have many such model and change between them even at run time.

Answer (score 0):

well it seems we could directly use the path of the jar file, as per the structure of resources (if you put it there). Previously this wasn't working for me as I had a few other errors.